# Single-letter camelcase fields not submitted in Struts 2 request

Tags: java, web-applications, struts2, struts2-interceptors

I have this very-2 strange mapping issue. All fields names like amount, newCase, status etc. are reaching perfectly to the struts Action but none of the single-letter camelCase fields are reaching the action. All are null.

For e.g.

```
public String callback() {
        System.out.println("nCase : " + nCase);
        System.out.println("Amount : " + amount);
        System.out.println("fAmount==============" + fAmount);
        System.out.println("fFee==============" + fFee);
        System.out.println("sStatus==============" + sStatus);
        System.out.println("sDetails==============" + sDetails);
        System.out.println("iTypeId==============" + iTypeId);
        ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this, ToStringStyle.SHORT_PREFIX_STYLE);
        return SUCCESS;
    }
```

The above code gives output :

```
nCase : 0.0
Amount : 2323.0
fAmount==============0.0
fFee==============0.0
sStatus==============null
sDetails==============null
iTypeId==============null
```

for the following request URL :

`http://localhost:8084/callback?fAmount=23.323&fFee=23&amount=2323&nCase=2323.23&sStatus=nitin`

I have proper getters & setters (checked many times now)

I have checked the interceptors also, and I'm using the defaultStack for this method/action

Comment: If you really want to use this properties then getter and setters must be like that: `getFAmount`, `setFAmount`.

Comment: you are right, the getters & setters created by the IDE automatically should be `WRONG`, they are setfAmount, instead of setFAmount.

Comment: Normally you'd include all the relevant information, like your getters and setters--*you* might think they're correct, but *we* can't see them, so they are obviously critical information. Also, what's the point of creating the toString if you just throw it away?